# Method argument conversion: 'tuple' has no attribute 'attribute'

Tags: python

I have a simple vector class that overloards several arithmetic operators:

```
class vec2:
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0

    def __add__(self,other):
        self.x = other.x
        self.y = other.y

    def __mul__(self,scalar):
        self.x *= scalar
        self.y *= scalar
```

However, somewhere else I call the method like this:

```
class foo:
    position = vec2()
    velocity = vec2()

    def update(self,dt):
        self.position += self.velocity * dt;
```

However, once I get to the update function, the interpreter gives an error:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'
```

inside the `__add__` function.

Why is "other" in `__add__` passed as a tuple, and not a vec2?

The entire code is [here](http://pastebin.com/rtar2dKg).

Comment: Mmh, can you post the code you used to get to `foo.update` ? You probably passed a tuple along the line. It may also be best to declare `x` and `y` as instance attrbutes (in a `__init__`) than as class attributes...

Comment: Actually the x and y get assigned 0 again in the __init__ of the vec2. I'll post the other code now.

Comment: You should *not* use `__add__`, etc. to modify your object in-place. Return a new instance with the new values instead. If you really want to modify self, use `__iadd__` instead.

Comment: @TravisG yse, `__iadd__` is `+=`, `__imul__` is `*=` ...

Comment: okay. @Pierre GM actually there's no more code to post. The update method is just called from the update method of another class, which, too, does nothing but iterate over a bunch of "foo"s and calls their update methods.

Comment: @TravisG Well, it's gonna be rather difficult to guess why you have a tuple in `__add__` without seeing any code calling `__add__`...

Comment: @PierreGM yes, sorry, I just noticed the typo. The line "self.position = self.velocity * dt" should have been "self.position += self.velocity*dt"

Comment: Your `__mul__` method is returning `None`, so your error should be `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x'`. There's something you're not showing us.  Also, what type is `dt`?

Comment: it's an integer. dt is the delta time between two frames. By the way I've since changed the methods corresponding to the answer by martijn pieters, and the error has changed: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'instance' and 'tuple'" on the line of self.position += self.velocity * dt .

Comment: Since there isn't a solution yet, I pasted the entire code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/rtar2dKg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return new vectors when using `__add__` and `__mul__`, and handle 'strange' types:

```
class vec2:
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return NotImplemented
        result = self.__class__(self.x, self.y)
        result.x += other.x
        result.y += other.y
        return result

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return NotImplemented
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y
        return self

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return NotImplemented
        result = self.__class__(self.x, self.y)
        result.x *= other.x
        result.y *= other.y
        return result

    def __imul__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return NotImplemented
        self.x *= other.x
        self.y *= other.y
        return self
```

To modify the vectors in-place, use `__iadd__` and `__imul__`; these *still need to return the new value*; this can be `self`.

Note that this does *not* handle just passing in a tuple of `(x, y)` coordinates. If you want to support that usecase, you need to specially handle it:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, position=(0.0, 0.0), velocity=(1.0, 1.0)):
        self.position = vec2()
        self.velocity = vec2(*velocity)

    def update(self, dt):
        if isinstance(dt, tuple):
            dt = vec2(*dt)
        self.position += self.velocity * dt;
```

Note also that you should not really use class attributes for your position and velocity values; I've used instance attributes instead above, and took the opportunity to set both position and velocity to sane values.

Demo:

```
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.position.x, f.position.y
(0.0, 0.0)
>>> f.update((1, 2))
>>> f.position.x, f.position.y
(1.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: changing the methods to your versions and adding overloads for iadd and imul changes the error: the interpreter now complains that "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'instance' and 'tuple'" on the line of self.position += self.velocity * dt . By the way I just noticed that it was a = and not a += before. Typo